# Cell Value in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, tablecell

I could post several links to articles of people asking the very same question, not necessarily on Stack Overflow, but I don't know why this does not work for me.

My code is:

```
int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.ID = "test" + testing.ToString();
lbl.Text = gvBatters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
upCompare.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);
testing++;
```

My problem is on this line:

```
lbl.Text = gvBatters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
```

The problem being `Value`. It does not like this, says I'm missing an assembly reference to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell`. I am in fact using `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

When I try the line like this:

```
lbl.Text = gvBatters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].ToString();
```

It shows up in my update panel with the label text as:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell
```

I am so close. All my Google searches say I should have `.value`, but visual studio says no.

Comment: I think that you need an index for the cells.                   lbl.Text = gvBatters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Value;

Comment: without seeing the gridview in question, I would put a break point on the line in question and use the watch window to navigate the row until you see the cell value you need

Comment: for proverbio:  i do have the cell index,  i need cell 1.  
for fnostro:  When debugging, i check the first check box in a search,  my row index is 0, so that is working.  visual studio will not let me compile when i try to reference the value of the cell

Comment: then remove the cell reference and the label assignment so you just have a call to gvBatters.Rows[rowIndex] so it will compile and run. Then start playing with the row reference in the watch window

Comment: it works perfectly. for some reason i simply cannot use .value, it isnt there.  other searches say .FormattedValue but that also is not there.  it wants to tell me i am missing an assembly reference, as stated in my original question, but that cant be it

Comment: i got it.  .text, not value.  didnt even see it in intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .text. I can't remember for sure but I think that will get the text if it's a bound field.

Comment: yea, thats what did it.  i didnt even see that originally in the intellisense,  it was at the bottom of a google search.  i wonder what happened to .Value